# How to grab a file on a password protected ssh

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, ssh

I am new to the IT world and still learning. I am trying to back up a script that is constantly changing and could be a bad day if it is ever erased or can't be accessed. I am trying to back up this script once a week onto my computer.  I have to ssh into the server which is password protected and I know the path to the file. How can I make that happen?

I read curl isnt an option since it is ssh. I saw a possible use of scp or rsync but im not certain.

Comment: "I am trying to back up a script that is constantly changing" This is *version control software*. Do not cobble something together out of bash scripts and duct-tape. Use something that's been built specifically for this purpose. The industry has largely consolidated on [Git](https://git-scm.com), for better or worse, which means there's a lot of resources on learning and using it.

Comment: For what it's worth, `git` can work between machines over SSH, it doesn't need any specialized server software, which might map really closely to your existing workflow.

Comment: PSA: Don't use password protected SSH. **Always** use keys.